# Store sensitive, non editable data client side

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have an angularjs app that is on a separate domain than my backend, and the users from my backend all have roles and permissions that allow them access to various areas and elements of my frontend.

Before, I was just storing to a cookie and checking as I needed through the use of angular services and whatnot, cool.

Now the permissions datum have reached the point where they are too big to store in a cookie in the browser.  And I'm avoiding Localstorage for fear of user tampering.

**The Question:**

How do I store the users sensitive data (*or anything sensitive, really*) that are too big for cookies on the client side in a manner that is safe and doesn't require API calls all the time to get?

I don't want to have to phone home every page change to get this data direct from the server when I need it, because I feel this would be really detrimental to the speed and flow of the site, not to mention the frequency at which this would need to happen would be ridiculous for my app.

Keep in mind that I do proper permission checking on the backend before carrying out any actions, but I'm more concerned about users tampering with their permissions to show certain elements that were removed on the frontside before.

What would be your solution or your advice on this?

Comment: On the client side there's not much of an option besides cookies and local storage. You could encrypt your data before storing. Otherwise there's only backend using SSL

Comment: Bah, thank you - LS seems OK because even if they changed a permission, I'm still checking server side - and some page elements are displayed based on these permissions. just seems like there should be a better way to do this,

Comment: There are other options other than local storage in modern browser but I do not thing any of them will give anything more than local storage in your case. Take a look here where local storage, web sql, indexeddb and filesystem as client storage mechanisms are discussed. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Answer (score 1):

If it ends up on the user's computer, regardless of whether it's in a cookie, in local storage, in the URL, in the browser's cache, or anywhere else on the user's computer, assume that the user can see it and mess with it. (You could encrypt it, but if your client-side logic knows how to decrypt it, you're back to step one.)

The best that you can do is exactly what you've described - be sure that the server only carries out authorized actions, and never trusts what the user tells it.